# Selenium 2: Webdriver : How to create my custom wrapper class for selenium components?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to develop my selenium testing framework using custom web elements like MyWebDriver, MyWebElement etc. instead of using those provided by selenium. I think I need to create custom wrapper classes for using my defined elements. I have been struggling for two hours. Can anyone please help me with this?

What I want to do is use custom elements in my `PageObject` Pattern like this :

```
private MyWebElement element;
private MyWebDriver driver;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like below

```
class MyWebElement implements WebElement {
   // override functions to define your behaviour
   @Override
public void clear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void click() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public WebElement findElement(By arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<WebElement> findElements(By arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
/// MANY MORE .....
}
```

Same for the webdriver

Comment: Welcome ! If it works please dont forget the mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: @star95 if you have issues with this and you are using eclipse, it's easy to do.  once you `implements WebElement` use eclipses Generate functionality to generate all of the fields that it can implement. You can click `Source->Override/Implement Methods`